# Meu spinner assume sempre a mesma imagem

Tags: android, imagem, spinners

Estou populando meu spinner através de um ArrayAdapter mas na ora de exibir ele mostra sempre a mesma imagem para todos os itens. Alguém consegue explicar onde está o erro?  Aqui está minha MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

GPSTracker gps;
AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
Spinner mSprPlaceType;

Button mBtnFind=null;
TextView textview=null;

Place[] mPlaces = null;

String[] mPlaceType=null;

String[] mPlaceTypeName=null;


LatLng mLocation=null;


HashMap<String, Place> mHMReference = new HashMap<String, Place>();

private int arr_images[] = { R.drawable.aeroporto_img,
        R.drawable.pe_img, R.drawable.atm_img,
        R.drawable.banco, R.drawable.autocarros, R.drawable.igreja, 
        R.drawable.hospital, R.drawable.cinema, R.drawable.restaurante,
        R.drawable.escola, R.drawable.museu, R.drawable.cafe, R.drawable.bar };



private static final float UNDEFINED_COLOR = -1;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

    mPlaceType = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_type);


    mPlaceTypeName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_type_name);


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, R.layout.mostra_spinner, R.id.mPlaceType, mPlaceTypeName);

    mSprPlaceType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spr_place_type);

    mSprPlaceType.setAdapter(adapter);  

    mBtnFind = ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.btn_find);



    class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{


        public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,   String[] objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mostra_spinner, parent, false);
            TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.mPlaceType); 


            if(position==0){

                // Default selected Spinner item 
                label.setText("Please select company");

            }
            else
            {
                ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.image);
                icon.setImageResource(arr_images[position]);

            }   
            return row;
            }

        }
```

Aqui minha activity_main.xml

```
<Spinner 
            android:id="@+id/spr_place_type"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image" 
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:prompt="@string/prompt" />
```

E minha mostra_descricao.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="3dip"
>
<ImageView

     android:id="@+id/image"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:src="@drawable/autocarros"/>
<TextView
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image" 
     android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
     android:textColor="@drawable/black"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:id="@+id/mPlaceType"
     android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="center"/>
```

Agradeço a ajuda

Comment: Faltou colocar o conteúdo de `R.array.place_type_name`. Você tem certeza que esse array possuí todos os place type que você espera?

Comment: O conteúdo de R.array.place_type_name está na pasta "values"-->"strings" E tem os places type que eu defini. Mas só aparece o drawable que está definido em "minha_descricao.xml" na ImageView e aparece essa imagem para todos os itens do spinner...